# How many simultaneous streams can be pushed into Wowza

Tags: wowza

My Wowza Streaming Engine Perpetual Pro Edition is running on home build Windows 8 server with:

```
2 cpu: Intel Xeon E5-2699 V3 - Tray ( 18 cores X 2 )

16 ram slots: 512Gb ram ( 32 X 16 )

1Tb SSD

Internet speed: 1gb upload and download
```

How many users can push 800 kb - 1 mb streams live video into my wowza server at the same time? please give me estimation based of this server and explanation. Can this setup support 1000 users at the same time?

Comment: it depends on many factors :will you use transcoding/transrating?  will you record incoming streams?  that processes use resources,  if you only receive an stream and forward it as is it will handle thousands connection and maybe the bandwidth available or network card is the one that will fail.

Comment: Cristian Sepulveda thank you very much and sorry for my very late response. There will be no transcoding or recording. But can it handle 400 simultaneous encoding and 4000 simultaneous playbacks ?

Comment: my experience is with live streaming and not VOD.  if you do not transcode/transrate the server works as a switch,  it receives the streaming and forward to the users,  there is no much use of the processor,  there is a little more use of ram...  but the bottle neck could be the network card. With that specification you could handle more that 2.000 simultaneous streams) maybe more),  to make a real test you should use a few amazon servers and implement XVFB to simulate as many simultaneous users as you need.

Comment: I agree with you on everything, but we have 1gb network card and 1gb upload/download Internet.The users push 800 kb so 800 kilobytes * 1250 =
1000 megabytes (1gb) does that mean we can only handle 1250 users in total based on that Internet speed and network card? beside that Wowza server only max use 10gb of ram...

Comment: that are the maths... you could add more NICs,  but  I read there is a limit of 5Gb due to java performance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you complete some testing by leveraging a [load test tool](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?122-How-to-get-Flash-RTMP-Load-Test-Tool).  This way any environmental factors will be taken into consideration and show up in your findings.  You will also want to consider your playback protocol as additional overhead may incur.